# WebGL / Three.js Different materials on one complex object (grid)

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

In order to increase performance i render grid to one THREE.Geometry() object in such loop:

```
build : function(){    // simplified

  square = new THREE.Geometry();
  face = 0;

  for( r = 0; r < this["rows"]; r++)
   for( c = 0; c < this["cols"]; c++)

       // creates square
       square.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3( x,  y, z));
       square.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3( x + w, y, z));
       square.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3( x + w, y - h, z));
       square.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3( x, y - h, z));

       square.faces.push(new THREE.Face4(face + 0, face + 1, face + 2, face + 3));

       face+=4;
  // end of loops 


  // This adds material to the whole grid.
  // How to do it to each individual square?

  squareMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        color:"white",
        side:THREE.DoubleSide
  });

  grid = new THREE.Mesh(square, squareMaterial); 
  scene.add(grid);
```

Lets say, i have a function that selects the set of vertices (one square) from the grid (mesh) how then apply color to only this set of vertices (square) ?

Comment: Did you see http://threejs.org/examples/canvas_geometry_cube.html where it shows how to set face colors?

Answer (score 0):

In your code you create a one object grid with one material. You cant set new material for part of object. In your case you can write your own shader and set them attributes  pos.x, pos.y and textere for example or draw your grid by parts (but this is a bad idea)

Comment: well, but how do set a material for part of a object ?!

Comment: "set new material for part of objec" ?

Answer (score 0):

first: create the grid as a plane geometry with multiple segments (10x10):

```
var planeGeo = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 100, 100, 10, 10 );
```

second: set materialIndex for whatever face you wish to change the material (eg color)

like so:

```
planeGeo.faces[5].materialIndex=1;
```

note: default materialIndex is 0;

then create two or more materials and put them into array:

```
var materialsArray= [
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0xFF0000, side:THREE.DoubleSide}), // matIdx = 0
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0x00FF00, side:THREE.DoubleSide}) // matIdx = 1
    ];
```

then create a multimaterial:

```
var multiMaterial = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materialsArray );
```

then create the mesh and add it to the scene:

```
grid = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeo, squareMaterial); 
scene.add(grid);
```

Hope it helps,

M.

PS:

maybe you'll have to rotate the planeGeo 180degs around X or Z axis - I think the PlaneGeometry is created with normals down - but not sure.

if needed, you'd do the rotation by:

```
planeGeo.applyMatrix ( new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationX(Math.PI) );
```